# Can't enable KVM for geymotion emulator to work with android studio

Tags: android, ubuntu, emulation, genymotion, kvm

Can any one help me I can't use HAXM as I am developing on Ubuntu and needs to install KVM. I have installed it successfully but can't enable it to enhance the speed of genymotion emulator and I have tried to enable through the android studio but according to many answers it needs to be enabled from Run->Edit Configurations->default->Android application but I can't find emulator tab as suggested by many answers. So can any one help me to enable kvm to work with genymotion or suggest better options except real device as I can't access database with my nonrooted samsung device.